# What does exit code 6 generally mean in c?

Tags: c

I just need the general meaning of it to work out a crash. Theirs nothing about it anywhere else that I could find.

Comment: Is it any system call you are making which is returning exit code 6?

Comment: Exit code from a function or from the whole program? Code 6 could be ENXIO No such device or address from errno

Comment: If you have a crash, the exit code cannot be 6. You probably mean something else like `errno`.

Answer (score 8):

Programs dying due to POSIX signal [`SIGABRT`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/abort.html) exit with an error code of `6` and the highest bit set.

`SIGABRT` is caused by calling `abort()` which might be due to an [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert)ion failing.

If the highest bit isn't set, it's an application-specific error code. You can type `echo $?` into your shell to see what error code the application right before exited with.

Comment: Depending on which shell you're using, the error code might be returned as unsigned integer, so `6` with highest bit set would appear as `134` when you `echo $?`. On the other hand, in python, the return code after running popen would be `-6` if it was aborted.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the C `main` function, there is no general standard of exit codes. It is a convention that a program returns 0 if it has been done successful and everything else otherwise. But even this is rather a thumb rule.

A specific application may have specific return codes which hopefully are documented somewhere.

After digging a little bit deeper I found [`exit` (cppreference.com)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit). I consider this because `exit()` is the other possibility to leave an application and I'm quite sure that the passed exit value is processed the same way like the return value of `main()`.

It mentions [`EXIT_SUCCESS`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status) and [`EXIT_FAILURE`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status):

> control is returned to the host environment. If exit_code is zero or
>   [EXIT_SUCCESS](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status), an implementation-defined status, indicating successful
>   termination is returned. If exit_code is [EXIT_FAILURE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status), an
>   implementation-defined status, indicating unsuccessful termination is
>   returned. In other cases implementation-defined status value is
>   returned.

On this site, there are also links to the respective C standards.

A similar statement can be found in the [Linux man page of exit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html):

> The C standard specifies two constants, **EXIT_SUCCESS** and
>   **EXIT_FAILURE**, that may be passed to exit() to indicate successful or unsuccessful termination, respectively.